# Alternative way to reset password

Tags: passwords, reset

I want to let user to reset password in case he/she forgot his/her password without sending reset code to his/her mail box. Actually I don't want to use emailing reset password system.

Is there any way to let user reset his/her password without using email in secure way?

Is 'security question' using safe?
Or what is safe to use?

Comment: You can send a new random password to his mail and manage a form to change password after authentication. Personally I don't like security question, but if you mean you don't want to use mail at all you must have a well defined way to identify the user, such as phone number.

Comment: I like but my web server doesn't support mail() function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The safety of the `secure question` will depend on the difficulty of the question itself. If you don't want to use the `mail()` function then you can try either of the following:

1. You can send an OTP to his registered phone number.
2. You can use more than 1 secure question to identify the user and then allow him to reset the password. But make sure that the standard of the question is high.

   For eg., avoid easy questions like `name of your first school`, `name of the birthplace`, etc. These questions can easily be answered by any other person close to the user.
   Try questions like- `What is the name of the city where you got lost?`, `What is the name of the teacher who gave you your first A?`, etc.

This will be safe as well as help you avoid `mail()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Safety can be improved with

- OTP on mobile.
- asking user to validate their personal information like:
  email address,
  last name,
  date Of Birth,
  last 4 digits of social security Number. etc..
- two layer Reset. send two different codes to (primary and secondary/mail and mobile) and verify both of them.

Answer (score 0):

if you have users registered mobile number. You can use One time password to authenticate users identity before letting him reset the password.